# Failing to set up inbound rules to accept traffic on Azure linux VM

Tags: azure

I have been trying to setup apache web server on my new Azure linux VM but i cant seem to find any luck, i have attached the image of my inbound rules. I do not know what could be the problem

[Inboud configuration.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PdWz.jpg)

Comment: Which ports do you have issues with? Can you ssh? If so, at least one port works. And what you posted is the Azure port management. What about the Linux VM's firewall configuration? FYI this should be posted to SuperUser, AskUbuntu, or the Unix & Linux stack exchange, since it's not programming-related.

Answer (score -1):

If you configured Network Security Groups (NSGs) on your virtual machine (VM) and are experiencing VM connectivity issues, this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-nsg-troubleshoot-portal) provides an overview of diagnostics capabilities for NSGs to help troubleshoot further.